# Encryption of sensitive user data - how to manage the secret data to generate the key

Tags: android, encryption, key-generator

First the end user must authenticate to log in the app. I want to encrypt the password he entered. How do you do that? How do you deal with the secret message to generate the key?

Same question with the user data information: I would like to make transparent the generation of the key. Is there a way to generate safely a secret message or ask the user to generate a secret message and hide it into the code?

Thanks to point me to some reading that explains how to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt the password. You should always use a one-way cryptographic hash function when storing user passwords, something like SHA256, so that the value cannot be reversed at any time if the application is compromised. When the user logs in, you should run their password through the hash function again and compare it to the stored value.

Comment: Understood for the password. For the user data your recommendations would be to store the secret message (to use to encrypt the data using AES256)  encrypted by SHA256? or use everywhere SHA256?

Comment: I am under the assumption that AES is safer than SHA. In my app the data is kept on the phone. The only risk (limited) for the user is to lose or to be stolen.

Comment: You should probably somehow use the plain-text password to encrypt the user data so that the key is not stored on the phone. You cannot use SHA256 if you plan to reverse the operation.

Comment: This discussion was very beneficial. Thanks a lot!